Create custom variables using foreach loop
Looking for a little help, I need to create custom PHP variables (that are built using the $key and $value fields of an array. I have tried a few options and this is as close as I've got to getting it to work.
JSON Example
{ "external_ref" : "MC\/E63", "oracle_product" : "Events", "event_minimum_notice" : "Yes", "read_guidance_pack" : "Yes", "event_management_plan" : "Yes", "risk_guidance" : "Yes", "risk_assessment" : "Yes", "public_liability_insurance" : "Yes", "license_required" : "Yes", "is_funfair" : "No", "area_of_ground" : null, "area_of_frontage" : null, "num_veh_type" : null, "num_size_tents" : null, "num_type_rides" : null, "num_size_foodstalls" : null, "food_types_sold" : null, "sewage_disposal" : null, "funfair_additional_info" : null, "event_road_closure" : "", "road_closure_requirements" : null, "road_involve_aroads" : "", "road_directional_signs" : "", "road_traffic_diversion" : "", "road_parking_restrictions" : "", "road_carpark_closure" : "", "road_event_parking" : "", "road_parking_details" : null, "road_parking_location" : null, "equipment_pyrotechnics" : "", "equipment_site_comms" : "", "equipment_live_entertainment" : "", "equipment_carnival_procession" : "", "equipment_aircraft_balloon_launch" : "", "equipment_living_history" : "", "equipment_reenactment_groups" : "", "equipment_motorcycles" : "", "equipment_market_stalls" : "", "equipment_bonfire_bbq_permit" : "", "equipment_animals" : "", "equipment_boat_hire" : "", "equipment_inflatables" : "", "equipment_marquees" : "", "equipment_barrier_fencing" : "", "equipment_power_supply" : "", "equipment_toilets" : "", "equipment_lost_children" : "", "equipment_alcohol" : "", "equipment_side_stalls" : "", "equipment_stewarding" : "", "event_type" : "", "event_name" : null, "event_description" : null, "event_location" : null, "event_ward" : "", "event_size" : "", "event_attendee_expectancy" : null, "event_start_date" : null, "event_end_date" : null, "event_days_times" : null, "event_date_siteprep" : null, "event_site_vacated" : null, "event_alternatives" : null, "event_free" : "", "event_admission_price" : null, "event_programmes_sold" : "", "event_proposed_price" : null, "event_charity_name" : null, "event_charity_regno" : null, "event_charity_donation" : "", "event_charity_info" : null, "event_public_enquiries" : null, "facilities_waste_collection" : "", "facilities_litter_disposal" : null, "facilities_toilets_required" : "", "facilities_toilets_details" : null, "facilities_stewards" : "", "facilities_traffic_stewards" : null, "facilities_banners_posters" : null, "facilities_banner_placement" : null, "facilities_market_stalls" : null, "hs_fire_equipment" : null, "hs_lighting_required" : null, "hs_electrical_certified" : null, "hs_firstaid_facilities" : null, "hs_emergency_vehicle_maintenance" : null, "hs_pa_system" : null, "hs_noise_pollution" : null, "hs_electricity_event" : null, "business_venue_confirmed" : null, "business_public_liability" : null, "business_insurer_name_address" : null, "business_policy_number" : null, "business_additional_information" : null, "person_first_name" : "John", "person_last_name" : "Doe", "contact_organiser_address" : null, "person_phone_home" : null, "person_phone_mobile" : null, "person_email" : "example@example.com", "contact_organisation_name" : null, "contact_organisation_address" : null, "UPRN" : null,"documents":[]}

PHP
    <?php
$incomingDataObj = json_decode($data); 

$incident = new RNCPHP\Incident();

    $oracle_array=array(
                "event_minimum_notice"=>"yes_no_3",
                "read_guidance_pack"=>"yes_no_10",
                "event_management_plan"=>"dog_chipped",
                "risk_guidance"=>"dog_fouling_sign_required",
                "risk_assessment"=>"blue_badge_fast_track",
                "public_liability_insurance"=>"sc_notified",
                "license_required"=>"blue_badge_address_provided",
                "is_funfair"=>"payment_successful",
                "area_of_ground"=>"back_office_no",
                "area_of_frontage"=>"new_emailaddress",
                "num_veh_type"=>"ownercompany_name",
                "num_size_tents"=>"property_name",
                "num_type_rides"=>"cc_address_cah",
                "num_size_foodstalls"=>"idea_of_who_is_responsible",
                "food_types_sold"=>"overdue_reason",
                "sewage_disposal"=>"text_field_100_1",
                "funfair_additional_info"=>"customer_address",
                "event_road_closure"=>"yes_no_2",
                "road_closure_requirements"=>"complaint_outcome_detailed",
                "road_involve_aroads"=>"blue_badge_id_provided",
                "road_directional_signs"=>"graffiti_surface_door",
                "road_traffic_diversion"=>"graffiti_type_racist",
                "road_parking_restrictions"=>"graffiti_type_offensive",
                "road_carpark_closure"=>"graffiti_type_other",
                "road_event_parking"=>"form_completed",
                "road_parking_details"=>"street_consultation",
                "road_parking_location"=>"blue_badge_reference",
                "equipment_pyrotechnics"=>"blue_badge_additonal_info",
                "equipment_site_comms"=>"prepared_to_be_a_witness",
                "equipment_live_entertainment"=>"sewage_involved",
                "equipment_carnival_procession"=>"reported_to_other_agency",
                "equipment_aircraft_balloon_launch"=>"graffiti_area_other_location",
                "equipment_living_history"=>"incidents_transferred",
                "equipment_reenactment_groups"=>"incident_found",
                "equipment_motorcycles"=>"do_you_need_a_bin_calendar",
                "equipment_market_stalls"=>"graffiti_window_glass",
                "equipment_bonfire_bbq_permit"=>"graffiti_window_frame",
                "equipment_animals"=>"numbered_street",
                "equipment_boat_hire"=>"yes_no_13",
                "equipment_inflatables"=>"bo_email_sent",
                "equipment_marquees"=>"graffiti_other_type_of_wall",
                "equipment_barrier_fencing"=>"graffiti_area_railway_bridge",
                "equipment_power_supply"=>"graffiti_area_utility_box",
                "equipment_toilets"=>"graffiti_window_frame_glass",
                "equipment_lost_children"=>"graffiti_area_bus_shelter",
                "equipment_alcohol"=>"notification_sent",
                "equipment_side_stalls"=>"cpm_run",
                "equipment_stewarding"=>"share_within_ward",
                "event_type"=>"event_type",
                "event_name"=>"cc_address_adr",
                "event_description"=>"text_area_2",
                "event_location"=>"cc_address_cf",
                "event_ward"=>"ward_area",
                "event_size"=>"event_size",
                "event_attendee_expectancy"=>"street_light_number",
                "event_start_date"=>"date_of_purchase",
                "event_end_date"=>"date_of_sale",
                "event_days_times"=>"names_of_all_persons_moving",
                "event_date_siteprep"=>"date_time_1",
                "event_site_vacated"=>"date_time_2",
                "event_alternatives"=>"text_field_255_1",
                "event_free"=>"fit_for_purpose",
                "event_admission_price"=>"type_of_container",
                "event_programmes_sold"=>"fee_paid",
                "event_proposed_price"=>"nsg_no_do_not_enter",
                "event_charity_name"=>"existing_landlord_name_address",
                "event_charity_regno"=>"destination_address_ln1",
                "event_charity_donation"=>"fridge_freezers_to_collect",
                "event_charity_info"=>"typedescription_of_dog",
                "event_public_enquiries"=>"refund_receipt_number",
                "facilities_waste_collection"=>"yes_no_4",
                "facilities_litter_disposal"=>"complaint_outcome_improvements",
                "facilities_toilets_required"=>"bin_message_left",
                "facilities_toilets_details"=>"cc_address_ld",
                "facilities_stewards"=>"yes_no_5",
                "facilities_traffic_stewards"=>"description",
                "facilities_banner_placement"=>"send_to_cah",
                "facilities_market_stalls"=>"moreinformation",
                "hs_fire_equipment"=>"primary_address_set",
                "hs_lighting_required"=>"yes_no_11",
                "hs_electrical_certified"=>"dead_animal_safety_hazard",
                "hs_firstaid_facilities"=>"graffiti_surface_brick_wall",
                "hs_emergency_vehicle_maintenance"=>"additional_information",
                "hs_pa_system"=>"building_work_started",
                "hs_noise_pollution"=>"diagnosis_letter_provided",
                "hs_electricity_event"=>"graffiti_location_property",
                "business_venue_confirmed"=>"personal_info_transferred",
                "business_public_liability"=>"ledger_purchase_order_no",
                "business_insurer_name_address"=>"proposed_property_address",
                "business_policy_number"=>"payment_amount_pc",
                "business_additional_information"=>"testing_outcome",
                "contact_organisation_name"=>"OwnercompanyName",
                "contact_organisation_address"=>"text_area_1"
                );
    
                // This loops through the array grabbing the JSON name (key) and the associated Oracle Field Name (value of key from array)
                foreach ($oracle_array as $key => $value) {
                   // Creates the PHP variable based on the item being looped
                   // Oracle field ID is the $value field
                   // JSON data is the $key field
                   // For each key we need to grab the corresponding oracle field to build its PHP variable that can then be used (refer to example below)
                   
                   // This prints _123 (which I set against the variable below) meaning $key is the variable but does not include the $value part
                   echo"$key: $value<br/>New Variable Value: ";
                   ${"$value"} . "_" . ${"$key"} = '123';
                   echo $$value . "_" . $$key;
                   echo "<br/><br/>";
                   }
                   ?>

I need the end variable to look something like this within my foreach loop (but I hadn't got that far):
$incident->CustomFields->c->$value = $incomingDataObj->$key;

Setting the value against ($incident->CustomFields->c->$value) sets the oracle field.

Why do you want to do this? What do you expect to achieve? Sounds like a recipe for unintended bugs, or even security issues. And it's overly complex, and almost certainly unncessary. If you want to access individual items from that associative array, just write $oracle_array["event_minimum_notice"]; (for example). You don't need to push everything out into separate variables in order to use the data.

I wonder if what you really meant to do was this: https://3v4l.org/0JbCA ? Your requirement statement was a little ambiguous, though. And I'm still baffled as to why you'd expect this to be useful in your application code.

To set the fields in Oracle I need to create the corresponding variable and set the value of it. I am using JSON (decoded is $incomingDataObj), I would then use this to set the value against the custom variable created. Because the JSON uses the $key field names that is the only way to reference which custom variable it corresponds to
Here is an example of what the custom variable will look like
// $incident->CustomFields->c->$value = $incomingDataObj->$key;

To set the fields in Oracle I need to create the corresponding variable and set the value of it...are you sure? What do you mean by "set the fields" exactly? Why do you need to create a variable for that? Surely you just need to construct a string? Can you show us proper detail of the Oracle-related code you're trying to feed this into, so we understand the context? I strongly suspect an X-Y Problem but it's hard to be sure, as your requirements are still vague / incomplete. You should [edit] your question to add more info, then it's easy to present it clearly

Can you show us what $incomingDataObj looks like, for a start?

I cannot share more unfortunately due to the nature of the project and work. This is the closest example I can give which I agree is ambiguous and leaves a lot of questions without very little answers (asking this question here weighed heavily on me) and I appreciate any help and feedback regardless :)

"I cannot share more unfortunately due to the nature of the project and work" ... The top secret excuse is counter-productive and likely to attract downvotes.

You don't have to show real data. Just show the structure of the $incomingDataObj variable with the field names, and some sample data. The exact datavalues I would guess are not related to the problem. The issue seems to be about mapping of fields (a list of which you seem to have already provided to us), but we really need to be able to see what we're working with on both sides.

BTW did you try my demo (https://3v4l.org/0JbCA)? I'm guessing it's not what you wanted, but then...I was guessing, so I suppose that's inevitable. It would be useful to at least rule it out. Or perhaps showing what has been misunderstood will help you to describe what you do want a bit more clearly :-)

edits made @ADyson I hope that helps. I will have a look at your demo now.

Also @ADyson thank you for sharing the XYproblem link, I had a good laugh reading that - You are correct, I didn't ask for what I really wanted - but part of me wanted to find out part of the mystery and then try and piece it together myself - although that would be counter productive to others seeking help with the same problem - so thank you :)

No problem! Thanks for the incoming data. The only mystery is now is what the CustomFields->c object looks like. Is this perhaps what you meant: https://3v4l.org/L9lap ? Specific examples of the necessary translation would have helped make this easier to understand!

Best example of Oracle custom fields is on their help site (https://documentation.custhelp.com/euf/assets/devdocs/cloud22b/Connect_PHP/Default.htm). If you use the search bar (bottom left) and search custom fields (then select Custom field sample code). Your answer has gave me exactly what I needed, thank you :)

Assuming the c property in the CustomFields object contains an object whose property names match the values in your $oracle_array, then this code should do what you need:
foreach ($incomingDataObj as $key => $value )
{
  if (isset($oracle_array[$key]) && !is_array($value))
  {
    if (property_exists($incident->CustomFields->c, $oracle_array[$key])) {
      $incident->CustomFields->c->{$oracle_array[$key]} = $value;
    }
  }
}

You don't need to create new variables at all - you simply need to reference the correct value in the $oracle_array, by using the $key from the incoming data.
Live demo: https://3v4l.org/L9lap
